# Entity Framework messing up row ids

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view

So I have a view that I have connected to Entity Framework, the view looks like this:

```html
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwRetroContractAggregate] AS 

 SELECT top 100 percent Rowid,
 RegionPeril,
 RIType,
 RIProgramme,
 RIContract,
 Level,
 TotalReinstatement,
 CcyCodeISO,
 ColumnType,
 TotalRecovery,
 MaxRecovery,
 MeanRecovery
 FROM NctWarehouseStaging.dbo.NctRetroContractAggregate<br>
 order by RegionPeril
```

When I run the view in SQL Server I get a unique row id for every row but when I run the statement below in entity framework it returns results with all sorts of random duplicate ids with no pattern. Why would this happen because I have never come across anything like this before?

```
var results = db.vwRetroContractAggregates.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with view. The results were completely unpredictable. It is because of entity framework can not understand what would be the unique key in your view. There is a trick with `ISNULL` in view. Read this for details:
http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/